# Inheriting Rails i18n validation error messages in the subclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, inheritance, i18n-gem, rails-i18n

### What I understand

Suppose I have a class with a handy validation like:

```
User < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :username, :format => {/regex/}, :message => :name_format
end
```

In this case, I can use `i18n` to make the error message translatable, by including the following in my `/config/locals/en.yml`:

```
en:
    activerecord:
        errors:
            models:
                user:
                    attributes:
                        username:
                            name_format: 'has the way-wrong format, bro!'
```

This is fine and generally really handy.

### What I want to know:

My question is: What happens when I have subclasses that inherit from User:

```
UserSubclassOne < User
    # extra stuff
end
UserSubclassTwo < User
    # extra stuff
end
...
UserSubclassEnn < User
    # extra stuff
end
```

Now the problem is that Rails can't find the translation `user_subclass_one.attributes.username.name_format`.

It complains:

```
translation missing:
en.activerecord.errors.models.user_subclass_one.attributes.username.name_format
```

I'd hope that Rails would look up the hierarchy of `UserSubclassOne` to `User` when searching for a string in `en.yml` and then notice when it gets a 'hit', but (unless I've done something horribly wrong) apparently that doesn't happen.

An obvious solution is to duplicate the data in `en.yml.en.errors.models` for `user`, `user_subclass_one`, `user_subclass_two`, etc, but my Rails-sense tells me that this is deeply wrong.

Any ideas, folks?

### Potential Complication:

`User` is defined in a gem `MyGem` that is included in a Rails engine `MyEngine` that is included in the full-on Rails app `MyApp` that defines `UserSubclassOne`, ..., `UserSubclassEnn`. I don't think this should matter though, since the validations are running in `MyGem::User`, which is where the `en.yml` file lives -- just wanted to let people know in case it does.

## Ultimate problem/solution:

So it turns out that the problem was namespacing. Recall that `MyApp` (which defines `UserSubclassOne`) uses `MyGem` (which defines `User`). It turns out `User` is actually in the namespace `MyGem` (this is not necessarily always the case), so the full declaration line at the beginning of `User` is not:

```
User < ActiveRecord::Base
```

but rather

```
MyGem::User < ActiveRecord::Base
```

.

When the i18n gem looks up the class hierarchy, it notices this namespace and searches for `my_gem/user`, rather than simply `user`, `my_gem.user`, `my_gem: user`, etc.

Thus I had to change my `en.yml` file to:
`/config/locals/en.yml`:

```
en:
    activerecord:
        errors:
            models:
                my_gem/user:
                    attributes:
                        username:
                            name_format: 'has the way-wrong format, bro!'
```

and bingo!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So it turns out that the problem was namespacing. Recall that `MyApp` (which defines `UserSubclassOne`) uses `MyGem` (which defines `User`). It turns out `User` is actually in the namespace `MyGem` (this is not necessarily always the case), so the full declaration line at the beginning of `User` is not:

```
User < ActiveRecord::Base
```

but rather

```
MyGem::User < ActiveRecord::Base
```

.

When the i18n gem looks up the class hierarchy, it notices this namespace and searches for `my_gem/user`, rather than simply `user`, `my_gem.user`, `my_gem: user`, etc.

Thus I had to change my `en.yml` file to:
`/config/locals/en.yml`:

```
en:
    activerecord:
        errors:
            models:
                my_gem/user:
                    attributes:
                        username:
                            name_format: 'has the way-wrong format, bro!'
```

and bingo!

Comment: A belated thank you. I have been pulling my hair out. I knew it was namespacing-related but couldn't get the errors to load without this help. The Rails Engine spec is almost useless. They completely left out this rather important detail.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Rails Guides for i18n regarding [Error Message Scopes (5.1.1)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models) for Active Record validation error messages, what you're attempting to do should work:

> Consider a User model with a validation for the name attribute like this:
>
> ```
> class User < ActiveRecord::Base
>   validates :name, :presence => true
> end
> ```
>
> *<...snip...>*
>
> When your models are additionally using inheritance then the messages are looked up in the inheritance chain.
>
> For example, you might have an Admin model inheriting from User:
>
> ```
> class Admin < User
>   validates :name, :presence => true
> end
> ```
>
> Then Active Record will look for messages in this order:
>
> ```
> activerecord.errors.models.admin.attributes.name.blank
> activerecord.errors.models.admin.blank
> activerecord.errors.models.user.attributes.name.blank
> activerecord.errors.models.user.blank
> activerecord.errors.messages.blank
> errors.attributes.name.blank
> errors.messages.blank
> ```
>
> This way you can provide special translations for various error messages at different points in your models inheritance chain and in the attributes, models, or default scopes.

So, in your case, assuming your classes look something like this:

**app/models/user.rb**

```
User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :username, :format => {/regex/}, :message => :name_format
end
```

**app/models/user_subclass.rb**

```
UserSubclass < User
  validates :username, :format => {/regex/}, :message => :name_format
end
```

and your **config/locales/en.yml** looks something like:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            username:
              name_format: 'has the way-wrong format, bro!'
```

then the message searching for a validation on `UserSubClass` should go:

```
activerecord.errors.models.user_sublcass.attributes.username.name_format # fail
activerecord.errors.models.user_sublcass.name_format                     # fail
activerecord.errors.models.user.attributes.username.name_format          # success
activerecord.errors.models.user.name_format
# ...
```

Assuming that your model files and yaml files look similar to what's above, then the potential complication you mentioned may be the issue, but obviously I can't be certain.

Comment: +1 for solid reference! I'll keep trying to see whether I've messed up or Rails isn't behaving as promised. When it's resolved, I'll mark this answer as accepted if appropriate.

Comment: So it turns out the main issue was indeed the "Potential Complication".
The correct key for `UserClass` should have been `my_gem/user_class` (rather than simply `user_class` or even `my_gem.user_class`).

Comment: That's a good point!  Would you be able to please add this detail as an edit to your question for the reference of anyone else with a similar issue? Also, could you either put what your solution ended up being in your question (and accept this answer), or put it in an answer of your own and accept that.

Comment: Will do, Paul! Thanks for the gentle prod ;)