# Rails engine ActiveRecord models I18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rails-i18n

I have a Rails app that depends on a separate Engine (stored in `vendor/engine_name`). That engine has an ActiveRecord object `Bar`:

```
module Foo
  class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
    # has an attribute bar_attr
  end
end
```

In that engine's `config/locales/en.yml` file, I've tried:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      bar_attr: "TEST"
```

I've also tried:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      bar:
        bar_attr: "TEST"
```

and:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      foo:
        bar:
          bar_attr: "TEST"
```

But no matter what, when I call `Foo::Bar.human_attribute_name("bar_attr")` from the parent app, I get "Bar attr" (e.g. the default human attribute name). Note that the same problem occurs with `Foo::Bar.model_name.human` when I try translations using:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    models:
      ...
```

I'm not sure if the app/engine structure is relevant, as I've tried the above three `en.yml` formats within the parent app's translations file too, with no luck.

What am I missing to get these model names/attributes to translate correctly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It took a bit of searching but I found an answer to this in another question [Inheriting Rails i18n validation error messages in the subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886629/inheriting-rails-i18n-validation-error-messages-in-the-subclass) as I was also trying to get i18n working for ActiveRecord in a Rails engine.

Based on the example above, the answer is probably something like,

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      foo/bar:
        bar_attr: "TEST"
```

Comment: It works! You are amazing. Once again, StackOverflow is better than official documentation.