# Converting Rails 4 App to Engine changes i18n locale namespacing causing I18n::MissingTranslationData errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines, rails-i18n

Converted my Pfoodler app to an engine. The Pfoodler engine is mounted in a test app. So far so good. Rails server launches and test app loads.

When I start the Pfoodler engine, it throws an error:

```
translation missing: en.pfoodler.static_pages.home.page_title
```

As a sidebar, in the app version, the i18n string is searched for and located as

```
en.static_pages.home.page_title
```

Converting the app to an engine has added the engine namespace to the i18n file search params. This has broken all the locale YAMLs, and there are dozens of files. I could fix the error by adding the pfoodler namespace to every file, but that seems like the wrong way to solve this problem.

I get the feeling there is a very simple solution, but I have not found it. What is the best way to solve this problem?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: After researching this at some length, I think by using the i18n-tasks gem/utility I can remap all of my existing locale YAMLs to the engine's namespace with a simple command line with params. If this works, it would be super cool, and then I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: This was very hlepful at resolving issues with porting app ActiveRecord validation error message translations to an engine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886629/inheriting-rails-i18n-validation-error-messages-in-the-subclass